# In ChromaDB, How to have a list of metadata dictionaries associated with each document and query them?

Tags: database, vector, chromadb

I have the following :

```
collection.add(
    documents=["doc1", "doc2"],
    metadatas=[{'data': '{"entity_text": "Patient", "entity_group": "species", "normalized_id": "[\'NCBITaxon:9606\']", "field": "Exclusion Criteria", "is_negated": "no"}, {"entity_text": "donor", "entity_group": "Subject", "normalized_id": "CUI-less", "field": "Exclusion Criteria", "is_negated": "no"}, {"entity_text": "pregnant lactating", "entity_group": "pregnancy", "normalized_id": "CUI-less", "field": "Exclusion Criteria", "is_negated": "no"}'}, {'data': '{"entity_text": "bilirubin", "entity_group": "drug", "normalized_id": "[\'mesh:D001663\']", "field": "Exclusion Criteria", "is_negated": "no"}, {"entity_text": "serum", "entity_group": "Biological_structure", "normalized_id": "CUI-less", "field": "Exclusion Criteria", "is_negated": "no"}, {"entity_text": "greater than 4 mg / dl", "entity_group": "Lab_value", "normalized_id": "CUI-less", "field": "Exclusion Criteria", "is_negated": "no"}, {"entity_text": "transaminases", "entity_group": "Diagnostic_procedure", "normalized_id": "CUI-less", "field": "Exclusion Criteria", "is_negated": "no"}, {"entity_text": "greater than 5", "entity_group": "Lab_value", "normalized_id": "CUI-less", "field": "Exclusion Criteria", "is_negated": "no"}'}],

 ids=["id1", "id2"]
)
```

Here `metadatas` is actually a list of two dictrionaries of dictionaries. Do you know if it is possible to query such a structure? If so, how?

I don't know how to write a query for this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't definitively answer your question, but I've been searching for info on doing something similar (storing a metadata field with multiple values) and I've not come across any mention anywhere of anybody doing this.  There's no mention that I've found in the ChromaDB docs about passing any value to a metadata field other than a simple string.  I'd say that, unless you've tried the .add() statement above and it was accepted without throwing an exception, we can probably presume that anything more than a simple string is just not supported.  I'm going to try embedding my keywords right into the text and querying against it using $in.  Mebbe that concept is worth considering in your case?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).